# Docker not running flask app after successful creation and running

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, dockerfile

I am not able to make Docker work on my Flask app

> My flask app is successfully running locally with no errors
>
> I m not getting any errors while building and running docker container based on my dockerfile

Docker successfully builds the entire image

Flask successfully runs locally

No errors are getting displayed on any end

I am copying the entire webapp to docker which has the required model.h5 file as well

#### My dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.5.3

# Grab requirements.txt.
ADD ./webapp/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt

# Add our code
ADD ./webapp /opt/webapp/
WORKDIR /opt/webapp

# ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT python ./app.py
```

#### My flask app code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
from scipy.misc import imresize
from urllib.request import urlopen
import cv2, numpy as np
import io, traceback
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
print(" Loading vgg16 keras DNN model > ")
model = load_model('model.h5')
print(" Model loaded ")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return " <h1> Flask is running </h1> "

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET'])
def predict():
    my_var = request.args.get('my_var', None)

    def predictor(url):
        file = urlopen(url)
        image = load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
        image = preprocess_input(image)
        yhat = model.predict(image)
        label = decode_predictions(yhat)
        label = label[0][0]
        return('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2]*100))

    predicted_value = predictor(my_var)
    return str(predicted_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: How do you run it and what does "not running" actually mean?

Comment: ran it using docker run -p 3333:5000  -d name

and by not running it's not deploying the web services at port 5000 or any other port, which is what the flask app is supposed to do

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem... tried also with `load_weights` and it doesn't work. No errors, nothing. Did you find an answer? I'm thinking of training the models in the server side again.